# Implementing condition_variable timed_wait correctly

Tags: c++, multithreading, time

I was reading through my STL implementation (standard-issue `g++ 4.6.2`) and came across this bit of race condition inside of `condition_variable`:

```
template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
cv_status
wait_for(unique_lock<mutex>& __lock,
         const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
{
    return wait_until(__lock, __clock_t::now() + __rtime);
}
```

Because `__clock_t` is an `std::chrono::system_clock`, we are tied to the whims of things like NTP (if the clock is moved back by a day after `__clock_t::now() + __rtime`, then we'll wait for a day).

The C++ standard (30.5.1) appears to get it right:

> 26
>
> Effects: as if
>
> `return wait_until(lock, chrono::steady_clock::now() + rel_time);`

Boost's `condition_variable` implementation has the same problem:

```
template<typename duration_type>
bool timed_wait(unique_lock<mutex>& m,duration_type const& wait_duration)
{
    return timed_wait(m,get_system_time()+wait_duration);
}
```

In fact, the underlying pthreads implementation seems to be the problem:

```
int pthread_cond_timedwait(pthread_cond_t *restrict cond,
   pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex,
   const struct timespec *restrict abstime);
```

because `abstime` is specified as "system time," not a monotonic clock.

So my question is: How would one implement something like `std::condition_variable::wait_for` correctly? Is there an existing implementation that gets this right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Note: Internally, `pthread_cond_timedwait` uses `gettimeofday`, which is bogus if you want to timeout in the time you specify: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_cond_timedwait.c;h=7278ec45b0eb0b48be50fe832fcd17ae988dca27;hb=HEAD

Comment: You're probably forced to use some other timer thread that uses a monotonic clock, and then wakes up your waiter if it expires before the waiter cancels it.

Comment: If I have to go that far (which I severely hope I do not), I'd rather just do a spin-wait inside my `wait_for` function (it looks like my `sleep_for` doesn't have that problem, as `nanosleep` does not have the same problem because it correctly uses `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`).

Comment: Please note that [the STL is not the standard library](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StlIsNotTheCppStandardLibrary).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to use a [`pthread_condattr_setclock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pthread_condattr_setclock.html) to tell the `pthread_condattr_t` to use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. The C code for doing this is pretty simple:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Set the clock to be CLOCK_MONOTONIC
    pthread_condattr_t attr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&attr);
    if (int err = pthread_condattr_setclock(&attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC))
    {
        printf("Error setting clock: %d\n", err);
    }

    // Now we can initialize the pthreads objects with that condattr
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t  cond;
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, &attr);

    // when getting the time, we must poll from CLOCK_MONOTONIC
    struct timespec timeout;
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    timeout.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + 5;
    timeout.tv_nsec = now.tv_nsec;

    // business as usual...
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &timeout);
    if (rc == ETIMEDOUT)
        printf("Success!\n");
    else
        printf("Got return that wasn't timeout: %d\n", rc);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm going to leave this open for a while because somebody might have an easier answer. The thing I'm not happy about here is that it means a `wait_until` is rather difficult to implement with a real-time clock (my best solution to that is to convert the provided `Clock` in the `time_point` into the `steady_clock`'s time and go from there...it is still subject to time-change race conditions, but if you're specifying a timeout in real time, you're already making a terrible mistake).

Comment: I doubt that there is an easier answer because it is a limitation of POSIX API. Note that not only `condition_variable` has the problem with timed wait but `mutex` has this problem too. Moreover for mutexes the situation is even worse because there is not such API as `pthread_mutexattr_setclock`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14248033/5447906.