# CLOCK_MONOTONIC and pthread_mutex_timedlock / pthread_cond_timedwait

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads, mutex

The [pthread_mutex_timedlock documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html) says that `abs_timeout` takes a `CLOCK_REALTIME`. However, we all know that it is inappropriate for timing a specific duration (due to system time adjustments).

Is there a way to make pthread lock timeout on `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` that is portable? The same goes with pthread_cond_timedwait.

Comment: It's not inappropriate. You just have to set your application's locale timezone to UTC.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi No. That doesn't prevent your real time clock from changing.

Comment: You can use a clock watcher thread that broadcasts all registered conditioned variables should the clock jump backwards.

Answer (score 24):

Having looked at the documentation and `pthread.h`, I can't find a way to make [pthread_mutex_timedlock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html) use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` so I assume that's not (currently) possible. For [pthread_cond_timedwait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html), however, you can use code like this:

```
pthread_condattr_t attr;
pthread_cond_t cond;
/* ... */
pthread_condattr_init(&attr);
pthread_condattr_setclock(&attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
pthread_cond_init(&cond, &attr);
```

I've omitted error code checking for clarity, but of course you should do that.

I assume that `CLOCK_REALTIME` is used because it's always available whereas in principle `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is optional. Also, I wonder if setting absolute timeouts makes it easier to recover after system calls get interrupted by signals and the like.

However, it does seem quite inconsistent that the clock can be set in some cases and not others - there really should be a `pthread_mutexattr_setclock()`, but alas there does not seem to be one. I guess you'll just have to hope someone doesn't set the clock!

Comment: This is good on Linux. `pthread_condattr_setclock` is not available on OS X and I have not been able to find a solution that works on OS X.

Comment: Seems like other people have run into this too: https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/issues/10

Comment: I'm about to do some experimenting, but I may have stumbled onto a solution over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338899/are-there-any-well-behaved-posix-interval-timers/31174803#31174803

Comment: Note that waiting on a cond var is different then waiting on a mutex. In many cases it might be ok, but mutex options like recursion or priority inheritance are not available!

Also note that waiting on a cond-var involves waiting on a mutex, so this can not be done with 100% CLOCK_MONOTONIC.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X and FreeBSD, you can use `kqueue` and `kevent`. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174803/432

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change clock for [pthread_mutex_timedlock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_timedlock.html) in GLIBC yet. Maybe it's due to backward compatibility, the MONOTONIC clock was introduced later than REALTIME, so there are a lot of software which is using such function and replacement CLOCK may affect on this.

Solution/s for Linux:

- You can found the source code of pthread_mutex_timedlock [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/pthread_mutex_timedlock.c.html) and it is based on syscall of [FUTEX](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) which uses MONOTONIC by default. So you can implement your own mutex by using this [article](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/the_futex.html) and it may be a good and robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved this question, with a workaround code.
I used this code in linux (c++)

myMutex.cpp

```
struct myMutexW_s {
  std::mutex m_wait;
  std::mutex m_thw;
  pthread_t tWId = 0;
  uint32_t tout = 1;
};

void Aux_Millisleep(int ms) {
  if (ms > 0) {
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = ms * 1000;
    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
  }
}

static void* myWait_ThFcn(void* arg) {
  myMutexW_ts* m_ = (myMutexW_ts*)arg;

  pthread_detach(pthread_self());
  int s = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
  if (s != 0) { printf("pthread_setcancelstate: FAIL %d, %X\n", s, m_); }
  s = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
  if (s != 0) { printf("pthread_setcanceltype: FAIL %d, %X\n", s, m_); }

  m_->m_thw.lock();
  Aux_Millisleep(m_->tout);
  m_->m_wait.unlock();
  m_->tWId = 0;

  return nullptr;
}

int myMutexTryLock(myMutexW_ts* m_) {
  return m_->m_wait.try_lock();
}

int myMutexWaitms(uint32_t tms, bool CrlI, myMutexW_ts* m_) {

  if (tms <= 0) return -1; // "timeout"
  if (m_ == nullptr) return -10;

  if (CrlI) m_->m_wait.try_lock();

  m_->m_thw.try_lock();
  m_->tout = tms;
  if ((ret = pthread_create(&m_->tWId, nullptr, &myWait_ThFcn, m_)) == 0) {
    pthread_yield();
  } else {
    printf("myMutexWaitms: FAIL %X, r:%d, th:%d, to:%d\n", 
             m_, ret, m_->tWId, m_->tout);
    Aux_Millisleep(m_->tout); // fake timeout
    return -20; // !!!!!!
  }
  m_->m_thw.unlock();
  m_->m_wait.lock();
  if (m_->tWId) {
    pthread_cancel(m_->tWId);
    return 0; // unlocked before timeout
  }
  return -1; // timeout

}

void myMutexUnlock(myMutexW_ts* m_) {
  if (m_ == nullptr) return;

  m_->m_wait.unlock();
}

myMutexW_ts* myMutexNew(void) {
  return new myMutexW_ts;
}

void myMutexDel(myMutexW_ts** m_) {
  if (m_) {
    if (*m_) {
      if ((*m_)->tWId) {
        pthread_cancel((*m_)->tWId);
        (*m_)->tWId = 0;
        (*m_)->m_wait.unlock();
      }
      delete (*m_);
    }
    (*m_) = nullptr;
  }
}
```

myMutex.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct myMutexW_s myMutexW_ts;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int myMutexTryLock(myMutexW_ts* m_) ;
int myMutexWaitms(uint32_t tms, bool CrlI, myMutexW_ts* m_);
void myMutexUnlock(myMutexW_ts* m_) ;
myMutexW_ts* myMutexNew(void);
void myMutexDel(myMutexW_ts** m_);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Usage is like a normal mutex.

I'm still testing its performance, but apparently it's been behaving well.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found another possible option (for Cpp), using timed_mutex
like this:

```
timed_mutex m_wait;

if (m_wait.try_lock_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(tout))) return 0;
  return -1; // timeout
```

https://cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/timed_mutex/try_lock_for/